# Прозрачность фоновой картинки label в qt

Tags: c++, qt, png

Нужно изменить фон label, а точней сделать его полупрозрачным.
Пробовал изменить прозрачность в фотошопе, не помогло.
Пробовал так:

```
ui->game1_label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);\nborder-image: url(:/img/ix.png);");
```

не помогло. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Решено.

Вся проблема была в ошибке:

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile qt

В фотошопе надо было отключить ***ICC-раздел: sRGB.***