# Проект на Pygame не открывает изображения, просто чёрный экран

Tags: python, pygame

Ошибка

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

```
    import pygame

    pygame.init()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

    pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes Game")

    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_1.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_3.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_5.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/right_6.png')]

    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_1.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_2.png'), pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_3.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_4.png'), pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_5.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/left_6.png')]

    bg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/bg.jpg')
    playerStand = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Home/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python37/site-packages/idle.png')


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    x = 50
    y = 425
    width = 60
    height = 71
    speed = 5

    isJump = False
    jumpCount = 10

    left = False
    right = False
    animCount = 0 

    def drawWindow():
        global animCount
        win.blit(bg,  (0,0)) 

        if animCount + 1 >= 30:
            animCount = 0

        if left:
            win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
            animCount += 1 
        elif right:
            win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y))
            animCount += 1 
        else: 
            win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))


        pygame.display.update()

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5: 
            x -= speed
            left = True
            right = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - 5: 
            x += speed
            left = False
            right = True
        else:
            left = False
            right = False 
            animCount = 0       
        if not(isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                if jumpCount < 0:
                    y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2 
                else:      
                    y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                isJump = False
                jumpCount = 10

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: если ответ помог, примите его

Answer (score 2):

[Была такая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865624/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-label-%D0%B2-qt). Надо убрать из png [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB). Попробуйте, например, в фотошопе открыть и сохранить без sRGB. Вот еще способы [удалить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile) sRGB из png. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]